# Auth0 is not redirecting to required url after logout

Tags: auth0

I need auth0 to redirect me to a given url: `http:\\localhost:3000\user-logout?id=xxx`
for that in auth0 dashboard I have this:
[image]

But when I call it using this url: `http://localhost:3000/logout?return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A%3A3000/user-logout?id=123` it is redirecting me to `http:\\localhost:3000`
I am missing something in settings?